# No such module GooglePlaces

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install the GooglePlaces pod so that I can use the autocomplete feature, however, after successfully installing it, xcode keeps telling me that no module is found.
[image]

It seems to be a problem with the GooglePlaces pod, as the others aren't throwing this error. However, we can see that in my pods folder, it is installed.

[image]

Here is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'TestApp5' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestApp5
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '7.3.0'
end
```

I have tried uninstalling Cocoapods, changing the GooglePlaces version, changing the platform version, and making a whole new Xcode project to test this.

Comment: Have you tried other installation forms such as SPM and/or the xcframeworks directly

Comment: No, I didn't want to use any other installation forms than cocoapods, I heard that if you use cocoapods and other installation forms in the same project, that you may encounter problems. Should I try?

Comment: I stopped using cocoapods when I switched to an M1 MacBook, I find them too much of a hassle. I was talking about replacing the installation method.

Comment: Yes ok I will try using the swift package manager

Comment: It does not seem possible to use swift package manager, i will try installing it manually

Comment: It does not seem to work, same error.

Comment: There is likely something else going on, make sure all your targets have access to the framework under "General"

Comment: I added the Googleplaces.xcframework to my targets, but it still does not work. This time, not in the code, but when I build it, it throws the error : "Framework not found GooglePlaces"

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, two days ago this was working perfectly, I accidentally went back to an old git version, and then it stopped working, however, I created new projects multiple times, and it still does not work anymore.